# How to make C# SerialPort.InputStream available across classes?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm working with an UART-device in an UWP-App. Furthermore I created a Connector class (for connecting the UART-Device) with a singleton-pattern. Now I'm stuck at the point to get the DataReader working: This snippet is working for Class1 (ViewModel for Page1):

```
private async Task Load()
{
    dataReader = new DataReader(Connector.Current.Device.InputStream);

            uint ReadBufferLength = 16;

            uint readbytes = await dataReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask();
            private byte[] RxBytes = new byte[12];

            if (readbytes > 0)
            {
                 dataReader.ReadBytes(RxBytes);
                Debug.WriteLine("Bytes recieved");

            } }
```

But when I try to access (with the exact copy of this method) the InputStream with a second class (On Page2), it gives me an exception.

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Unfortunately the [API of the InputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.inputstream.aspx) isn't that clear about getting multiple DataReaders on the InputStream, so I'm guessing that this is not possible.

I need the bytes from the Inputstream in Class1 and Class2 (at the same time). Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading the data into a variable - which you lock during the reading (thread safety) - and than access that variable from your classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is most likely due to the fact that you've already read from the InputStream (the "application request" in your exception).

One of the easiest ways to get it so that you can read it multiple times would be to create a simple wrapper around it to cache it for you so you can read it as many times as possible.

```
public static class InputStreamWrapper
{
    private static DataReader data;

    public static DataReader InputStream 
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                data = new DataReader(Connector.Current.Device.InputStream);
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

If you happen to have some reason to read different streams, you could always add a `Reset()` method to the class that will set `data` back to `null` so it will read again.